# Dating my TA after the fall semester

Tags: united-states, etiquette, teaching-assistant

Long story short, my TA and I have expressed romantic feelings for each other; I’m a man while she’s a woman, if that matters.  We’ve not acted on our feelings yet, but now that grades are submitted for the fall semester, we’d like to proceed with going on a first date.

My questions are:

- Are there any potential issues with dating her?  I don’t foresee that she’ll be my TA again.
- Should we report our relationship to the department chair?

Comment: Are you in the same dept?

Comment: Is she "your TA" because you're faculty and she worked for you or because you're a student and she was a TA in a class you took?